# Aggregation from multiple tables not counting

Tags: sql, aggregation

I got this selection:

```
select EN.NAME_COMP, EN.CODE_CODE_COMP, sum(IT.AMOUNT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
from COMPANY EN, SALARY IT
where IT.NO_ACC = EN.NO_ACC
group by EN.NAME_COMP, EN.CODE_CODE_COMP, IT.AMOUNT
;
```

sum(IT.AMOUNT) must totalize all amount from NAME_COMP, but instead of this, it display every NAME_COMP separately and with separately amount, it not make his SUM

---

```
NAME_COMP                        CODE_CODE_COMP          TOTAL_AMOUNT 
------------------------------ -------------------- --------------
COMP 1                        23                           1500.5
COMP 1                        23                            500.5
COMP 4                        12                          2100.75
```

Comment: Remove IT.AMOUNT from GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You are the best :) thx

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause and get used to the "modern" (30 years old) explicit JOIN operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just don't know how to use with join operator, you can modify it, I will be glad to see another version. thx